# I have updated my python to 3.6 and now i am facing problem that . I am not able to install any package .can you provide solution?

Tags: 16.04, apt, python, dpkg

**Error is this**

I am install git and getting this error .
`sudo apt-get install git`

```
Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.3).
```

The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

```
  libpython3.6-minimal libpython3.6-stdlib python3.6-minimal   
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.  
1 not fully installed or removed.  
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y  
Setting up python-lockfile (1:0.12.2-1) ...  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>  
   ` from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \  `
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>  
    `from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser  `
`ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser' ` 
dpkg: error processing package python-lockfile (--configure):  
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 `python-lockfile `  
**E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
```

**I am thinking to format , please provide solution**

Comment: sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean &&
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal python-lockfile

Comment: I have tried this . This is not working. when i run above it say `ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-lockfile (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-lockfile
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
`

Comment: Run `python --version` and let us know the output of this command.

Comment: version is `Python 3.5.2` .

Comment: Your system python scripts are all 2.7, so did you keep the /usr/bin/python link pointing to python2.7 ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that . I think i have removed that . how can i do so ?

Comment: When i did `sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python` then run python -V it says `bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory`

Comment: `sudo ln -s python2.7 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: default `python2.7` binary location is `/usr/bin/python2.7`

Answer (score 2):

`ConfigParser` was used in Python2, in Python3 it is renamed into `configparser`. By default, `python` points to `python2.7` executable, but in your system, `python` command points to `python3` executable which is causing this error. Run `sudo ln -s python2.7 /usr/bin/python`.

Comment: this solve the issue . but i am having many issue with python . will format .

Comment: You must either give a full path (/usr/bin/python2.7) to the target or change default directories to /usr/bin (cd /usr/bin) before the command.  Otherwise, the link will be "dangling".

Comment: as `python2.7` executable is already in `/usr/bin/` it is not necessary to add full path name. default ubuntu installation is also arranged in this way, I don't know if you can call that dangling.

Answer (score 0):

When using Ubuntu 16.04, you must be cautious with the Python version that you use, because **Ubuntu 16.04 heavily relies on python 3.5**.

I, too, installed python 3.6, and in the /usr/bin/ folder, I had the (very, very bad) idea to change the link python3 --> python3.5 into python3 --> python3.6 . My system crashed little time after that (Unity crashed, many programs crashed, I was back to CLI after boot).

I fixed it and I found out that this simple link had messed it all. Since then, whenever I want to use a non-standard Python version (standard being 3.5 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS), I make some container (I use virtualenv) and work from there. Since then, I use multiple isolated Python environments (2.7, 3.5, 3.6; with tensorflow, cuda, cuDNN etc.) and everything works just fine.

Hope this helps!